# Generators of simple Lie groups and finite word length

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected simple Lie group with finite center. Let $a=\mathrm{exp}(X)$ be a semisimple element. Then we can decompose the lie algebra of $G$ into the direct sum of the eigenspaces of $\mathrm{ad}(X)$, namely $\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus \mathfrak{g}_\lambda$.

By simplicity, $\bigcup_{\lambda \neq 0} \mathfrak{g}_\lambda $ generates $\mathfrak{g}$ as a Lie algebra.

Is it true that not only does $S=\bigcup_{\lambda \neq 0} \mathrm{exp}(\mathfrak{g}_\lambda)$ generates the group $G$, but there is some integer $N$ such that any element of $G$ is a product of at most $N$ element of $S$?

I believe that this is true for $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ with the classical generation by transvections.